# dynamic join based on select column content (postgres)

Tags: postgresql, join, select, dynamic

This question is for postgres, but I only know how to write basic mySQL so please forgive any incorrect syntax in my explanation. (switching from another technology (mongo), need to know if postgres can accommodate).

Here are some example tables:

```
table ``profile``
+---------------------------------------+
| id  | name       | ver   | os | os_id |
+---------------------------------------+
| 221 | test1      | 0.0.1 | 1  | 12    |
| 222 | test2      | 0.0.2 | 2  | 13    |
| 223 | helloworld | 1.0.0 | 2  | 12    |
+---------------------------------------+

table ``linux``
+------------------------+
| id  | distro | env     |
+------------------------+
| 12  | arch   | openbox |
| 13  | debian | kde     |
+------------------------+

table ``windows``
+-----------------------+
| id | release    | sp  |
+-----------------------+
| 8  | Windows 8  | sp1 |
| 9  | Windows 10 | sp2 |
+-----------------------+

table ``android``
+---------------------------------+
| id | release     | image | root |
+---------------------------------+
| 12 | lollipop    | uri   | 1    |
| 13 | marshmallow | uri   | 0    |
+---------------------------------+

table ``oslist``
+--------------+
| id | name    |
+--------------+
| 1  | android |
| 2  | linux   |
| 3  | windows |
+--------------+
```

The main query pulls specific row from the profile table, in this example, id 223:

```
SELECT profile.id, profile.name, profile.ver, profile.os, profile.os_id FROM profile WHERE profile.id=223 ...
```

But I also need to add the row data from the respective operating system in the result. It is not ideal to make a second query, so I would like this as a subquery or JOIN.

So in the same example, the query needs to *understand* that profile.os is 2, and to check table.oslist for an id of 2, see that it is linux, and then use that name to dynamically JOIN the appropriate table: JOIN linux ON linux.id=profile.os_id

The result would then be this:

```
+---------------------------------------+
| name       | ver   | distro | env     |
+---------------------------------------+
| helloworld | 1.0.0 | arch   | openbox |
+---------------------------------------+
```

Had the profile id been 221, the result would have been this instead:

```
+----------------------------------------------+
| name       | ver   | release  | image | root |
+----------------------------------------------+
| test1      | 0.0.1 | lollipop | uri   | 1    |
+----------------------------------------------+
```

Is this possible? Is using the oslist table required, or can there be some other pre-written function it can feed it into (like a switch-case sort of thing)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any single query cannot return a varying number of columns. You can however include all possible values or return the results as JSON. On the bright side, you have a limited number of different OSes, so this is doable.

```
SELECT
  profile.name, profile.ver,
  oslist.name AS os,
  android.release AS android_release, android.image, android.root,
  linux.distro, linux.env,
  windows.release AS windows_release, windows.sp
FROM profile
  LEFT JOIN oslist ON (oslist.id = profile.os)
  LEFT JOIN android ON (profile.os = 1 AND android.id = profile.os_id)
  LEFT JOIN linux ON (profile.os = 2 AND linux.id = profile.os_id)
  LEFT JOIN windows ON (profile.os = 3 AND windows.id = profile.os_id)
WHERE profile.id = 223
```

For JSON output, try the following:

```
SELECT
  jsonb_strip_nulls(
    jsonb_build_object(
      'name', profile.name,
      'version', profile.ver,
      'os', oslist.name,
      'release', coalesce(android.release, windows.release),
      'image', android.image,
      'root', android.root,
      'distro', linux.distro,
      'env', linux.env,
      'sp', windows.sp
    )
  ) AS result
FROM profile
  LEFT JOIN oslist ON (oslist.id = profile.os)
  LEFT JOIN android ON (profile.os = 1 AND android.id = profile.os_id)
  LEFT JOIN linux ON (profile.os = 2 AND linux.id = profile.os_id)
  LEFT JOIN windows ON (profile.os = 3 AND windows.id = profile.os_id)
WHERE profile.id=223
```

This will give you

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| result                                                                           |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| { "name": "helloworld", "version": "1.0.0", "distro": "arch", "env": "openbox" } |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: A rather simple solution to what I thought was a complicated problem. This will certainly work due to the finite number of os tables. cheers!